# how to make multi_friends relationship

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have database contains those tables:
user, post, like and comment.
I was able to make diagram to show relationship between them.

**one user has many posts, many likes and many comments.**

**one post or comment has many likes.**

**post can have comment also.**

see diagram :[image]

my question is how can i make friendship for user, (user has many friends)
please give me a diagram or strategy to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table

```
FRIENDS
---
SOURCE_USER_ID  FK to USER
DEST_USER_ID    FK to USER
```